# Embedded Systems: Designing an API that monitors an address

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded

This question was tossed as a starting point in a technical interview at a semi-conductor company. I guess there are no right ans - the purpose of this open ended question is to gauge the engineer's depth and comfort level. Question:- design an API which monitors an address and returns when the address contains a specific value:-

```
void reach_target_value(volatile int* addr, int value);
```

My naive solution was something like this:-

```
void reach_target_value(volatile int* addr, int value)
{
  while(*addr != value)
  {
    //Do nothing - spin in a tight loop
  }
}
```

Now obviously in a multi processing/ multi threaded environment, it might miss to return if the address happens to reach the target value when the executing process/thread is context switched. Leaving this case how to enhance the code to ensure it works well in a multi-threaded environment where multiple threads would be monitoring the same address with different target values? Thanks for reading - would appreciate your suggestions - code - pointers!

Comment: With most embedded systems, the processors, co-processors, or  memory "sniffers", provide a way to monitor memory accesses to a limited amount of memory, perhaps just one or two locations or perhaps a range of locations, and provide a break, interrupt, or trace on an access or only on writes. For software, some thread or interrupt routine could be run at regular intervals to monitor for a change. This would reduce the overhead depending on the "sampling" rate, but could miss a pair of updates that result in the original value being written back to memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a question that can (as you have assumed) be answered in the broadest possible way. The point with that interview question is not your answer (with the preconditions you got, you cannot answer it anyhow) - but rather your clarification questions, whether you have the methodology and skills to track down the problem by encircling it with increasingly more detailed questions.

Possible answers range from your "naive" busy-wait approach, which can be a perfectly valid solution in, for example, an AVR Tiny that is waiting for an interrupt and has absolutely nothing else to do, over using a timer task to frequently watch for changes to using `mprotect` on an embedded Linux system to watch a variable "in hardware" and receive a signal as soon as some code writes to that memory (And lots and lots of other ways to approach the problem).

What the "proper way" of doing things is, depends on a large number of preconditions that your interviewer was actually expecting you to ask, (and without answers on these, there is no possible way to answer) like

- Are we talking bare metal or is there an RTOS, maybe even embedded Linux or Windows?
- If bare metal, are we maybe working in an environment that has support for watching memory changes (some ARM embedded CPUs have)?
- Does the *system* have any other tasks while it waits for the memory to change?
- Do we have timers, and if yes, how frequently is the variable expected to change (i.e. how big is the chance we might miss a change if we use a timer approach, and what are the minimum expectations for reactions to a change, are we allowed to miss changes)?
- Are we working in a virtual memory environment supporting page faults that could help us through `mprotect`? Related: Do we have any hardware that could help us here, like an MMU or hardware watchpoint support?
- In case we have multiple threads that wait for a change, how many are they, is this a constant number we know before, or do the consumers change over time?
- How is *writing* to the memory address synchronized between the tasks that change it? Can we maybe fence in the access by mutexes or similar?
- ....

And, to sum it up: The interviewer was definitively not expecting to see code - they expected to hear your clarification questions and your ability to fence in the problem, in the end coming up with a viable solution to an (apparently simple) problem. I actually find this a quite nice interview question.

Comment: I would also have mentioned [debugger watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) and operating system features (like [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) ...) and processor features related to them; perhaps consider *implementing* such a feature if relevant

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Although you might have seen the "..." at the end of the list: Debugger watchpoints are maybe not so useful for *implementing* watches in an embedded application, the hardware mechanisms behind them are relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I think repeat checking in a loop is not a good design.

Actually, This question has the same technical point with the following one:
[Watch a memory location/install 'data breakpoint' from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689019/watch-a-memory-location-install-data-breakpoint-from-code)

When you detected memory changes, it is the timing to check the value and to determine whether to return.

Comment: That design might be *inevitable* - On an AVR, for example (after all, this question is tagged as "embedded"), if you want reliable detection of variables changed by ISRs, there's not much else you can do.